# UICollectionViewCell quickly showing data from a previous cell when setting values

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I am having an issue with a custom `UICollectionViewCell` where I am able to quickly see a flash of data from a previous cell when I reload the collection view.  The cell ultimately ends up with the correct data, however.

My custom cell has a `UIButton` which I am setting the title of in the `func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {}` delegate method.

I have tried, for example: `cell.myButton.setTitle("", for: .normal)` to "clear" the previous value that had been set upon each item in collection view before setting the actual title that I wish to use.

Any ideas what might be causing this?

Thanks for your help in advance!

Comment: Set previous cell's data as nil if they have image or something before you show new data.

Comment: Are you using `dispatch_async()` calls to set the values? `collectionView:cellForItemAtIndexPath:` is supposed to run on the main queue, so using GCD is pointless and will make that "lag" between dispatching and actually executing that specific task. What's your actual implementation of that delegate method?

Comment: Thanks for replies, guys.  I have changed my button type to "Custom" which is fixing this issue.  Not entirely sure why, if you have any ideas I would love to know, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Though you have already figured out the work around of setting the button type to `custom` (am not sure how its solving your problem though), just wanted to let u know that `cellForRowAtIndexPath` isn't the great place to clean the already loaded cell.

If you have your custom cell, then you should consider overriding `prepareForReuse()` and clear the cell before it gets reused.

```
override func prepareForReuse() {
  //clear your cell here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This problem usually happened when you didn't set the data properly. As the example below, alphabets array was used to populate collection view data. In cellForItemAt method, we set the button title only when the alphabet is equal to A. This cause the flashing problem because we didn't handle the situation when the cell didn't equal to "A". To fix it, we need to handle the condition when it is not equal to A.

```
let alphabets = ["A", "C", "A", "D", "E"]

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cellIdentifier", for: indexPath)
    let alphabet = alphabets[index.row]
    if alphabet == "A" {
        cell.myButton.setTitle("Success", for: .normal)
    }

    // To fix it, handle the case when alphabet is not equal to "A"
    else {
        cell.myButton.setTitle("", for: .normal)
    }

    return cell
}
```

Comment: Hey man, thanks for your response it is much appreciated.  I have just figured out that if I set the button to type "Custom" I no longer have this issue.  Very weird, I have no idea why this fixes it.

Comment: Welcome. Yeah very weird.

Comment: I suggest you to always use the custom value for your button, because with the system button you have some default styles, according to documentation : "A system style button, such as those shown in navigation bars and toolbars."